# Reinstall site collections after language pack installation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, language-pack

I have two site collections, with a bunch of sites under them.
Now I have been asked to change the language of the site.

I have successfully installed the language pack, and completed all the tasks related to it.

Now I want to change the language on the existing site.
I have found infomation saying that I cant do this on already installed sites and site collections, since their template is set to the original language.

I wonder, is it any possibility to keep the content of the existing sites, and only install the templates again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no supported way to change the Site Collection Default Language once it is created.

- So you can delete the exisiting site collection and recreate the site collection with correct language, but this way you will lose all content.
- other way, you can create another Site collection with new language and then manually copy the data from old site to new.
- Another way, just change the User language settings, see if that solves the problem.

**Note: Use on your own risk.**

- Another method is to directly update the template languge in SQL server. **this is totally unsupported by MSFT**. But what I am thinking, Copy the Site collection and restore in the test farm and change the language using SQL query. To test it.

[How to Change the Language for a SharePoint Site](http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2014/03/how-to-change-the-language-for-a-sharepoint-site/)